# PHP mysqli search error

Tags: php, search, mysqli

I'm trying to return results from a database using a search bar and mysqli. However, my code isn't working and doesn't make it to the end.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
include("../dbconnect.php");
if (!isset($_POST['search'])) {
    header ("Location:tornado.php");
}


$search_sql="SELECT * FROM `TABLE 74` WHERE `COL 4` LIKE '%$_POST[search]%' OR `COL 3` LIKE '%$_POST[search]%'";
$search_query=$mysqli->query($search_sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($search_query)!=0) {
$search_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($search_query);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Results</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>Search Results</p>
<?php if(mysqli_num_rows($search_query) !=0) {
    do{ ?>
    <p><?php echo $search_rs['`COL 4`']; ?></p>
<?php   } while ($search_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($search_query));
} else {
    echo "No results found";

}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm confused because earlier, "No results found" would come up. Now nothing happens at all even though I have resorted back to the code that worked the first time. Is there something I'm missing? If possible please explain what I have done wrong.

Comment: NOt your problem, but while do...while construct where you want to loop through your results.  In the first iteration, you are trying to echo out values that do not yet exist (`$search_rs`).  Try straigth while loop.

Comment: Try do echo $search_sql and POST here to see if the POST data is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have forgotten to include the `$` in `mysqli` in

```
$search_query= mysqli->query($search_sql);
              ^
```

`$mysqli` being your DB connection.

which should read as

```
$search_query=$mysqli->query($search_sql);
```

Having checked for errors in your query, would have signaled it.

```
or die('There was an error running the query [' . $mysqli->error . ']');
```

---

**Edit:** (tested)

This worked for me:

```
<?php

$DB_HOST = "xxx";
$DB_NAME = "xxx";
$DB_USER = "xxx";
$DB_PASS = "xxx";


$mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if($mysqli->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Connection failed [' . $mysqli->connect_error . ']');
}


$search_sql="SELECT * FROM `TABLE 74` WHERE `COL 4` LIKE '%$_POST[search]%' OR `COL 3` LIKE '%$_POST[search]%'";

$search_query=$mysqli->query($search_sql);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Results</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>Search Results</p>

<?php 

if(mysqli_num_rows($search_query) > 0) {

    while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($search_query)){

    echo $rows['`COL 4`'];

    } 
}

else {
    echo "No results found.";
}


?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that. However, my code still doesn't work. I can't seem to find a problem with the rest of the mysqli code.

Comment: @user3474814 You're welcome. Let me see what I can do. If I can't find out why, then I will simply delete my answer. I will keep you posted.

Comment: @user3474814 Reload my answer and see if by dropping `if(mysqli_num_rows($search_query) !=0) {
    do{` will work. Or remove the `;` in `while ($search_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($search_query));` and adding `{` in its place.

Comment: @user3474814 Reload my answer again and look under `Edit: (tested)`. It worked for me, I tested it now, with a good and wrong query.

Comment: It works great, thanks!The only thing now is that it's not actually showing the results. The page remains blank when results are found.

Comment: Never mind, that was an easy fix. I just had to remove the ` from ['`COL 4`']. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look right:

```
$_POST[search]
```

Try this:

```
"SELECT * FROM `TABLE 74` WHERE `COL 4` LIKE '%$_POST[\'search\']%' OR `COL 3` LIKE '%$_POST[\'search\']%'"
```

You might also want to add brackets:

```
"SELECT * FROM `TABLE 74` WHERE `COL 4` LIKE '%{$_POST[\'search\']}%' OR `COL 3` LIKE '%{$_POST[\'search\']}%'"
```

Make sure `COL 4` is actually called that an not `COL_4`.

Finally, you should probably look into [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), that looks pretty vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Good luck!

Comment: Actually yes, `$_POST[search]` is ok, but doing `'%$_POST['search']%'` would throw the following `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in...` - I've found a solution for the OP which I've tested before posting.

Comment: Oh, yeah I didn't escape the thing. How is `search` working..? Is it a constant?

Comment: Cool if you found a solution. :-)

Comment: Even escaping `'%$_POST[\'search\']%'` or `'%$_POST[\"search\"]%'` would still throw the same error. It won't be treated as a constant even though it theoretically is, *strangely enough*.

Comment: Si signore :) the solution I've given the OP worked, yet I haven't heard back from that person since. Si, io sono parlo italiano anche ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for rows matching either `COL 4` OR `COL 3`. So in case you have rows matching the search string in `COL 3` with empty `COL 4` will result in the behavior you are seeing right. Also noticed that your search result display is using back-ticks inside the variable can you trying removing those too, so try doing something like:

```
  <?php if(mysqli_num_rows($search_query) !=0) {
    do{ ?>
    <p>
      <?php echo 'Col 4 - ' . $search_rs['COL 4']; ?>
      <?php echo 'Col 3 - ' . $search_rs['COL 3']; ?>
    </p>
  <?php 
    } while ($search_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($search_query));
  } else {
     echo "No results found";
  }
```